# Error in installing ggplot2 package in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using R 2.14.1 in Ubuntu (over an SSH connection). I can't load the ggplot2 package, every time I do it shows this

> ERROR: dependency ‘Rcpp’ is not available for package ‘plyr’  removing
>   ‘/home/amitra/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/2.14/plyr’
>
> ERROR: dependencies ‘plyr’, ‘Rcpp’ are not available for package
>   ‘reshape2’    removing
>   ‘/home/amitra/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/2.14/reshape2’
>
> ERROR: dependency ‘plyr’ is not available for package ‘scales’
>   removing ‘/home/amitra/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/2.14/scales’
>
> ERROR: dependencies ‘plyr’, ‘reshape2’, ‘scales’ are not available for
>   package ‘ggplot2’ removing
>   ‘/home/amitra/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/2.14/ggplot2’

Need help please.

Comment: Your R version is ancient. It will be easiest to just upgrade R, probably. Otherwise, you'll have to manually install old versions of the packages.

Answer (score 1):

Package `Rcpp` [is only available for R 3.0.0+](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/index.html).  Since other packages, including `plyr`, depend on `Rcpp`, the easiest way to fix this is upgrade to R 3.0.0 or greater.